# Navigation title not showing on Watch OS (IDE: Xcode)

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

I'm coding according to `SwiftUI` tutorial from **Apple**. But the preview result on my end which was without navigation title was different from **Apple** though the code was the same and `.navigationTitle` was working well on iPhone simulator. Anyone who could help finding out the reason? Will be appreciate!

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkDetail: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    var landmark: Landmark

    var landmarkIndex: Int {
        modelData.landmarks.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == landmark.id })!
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                CircleImage(image: landmark.image.resizable())
                    .scaledToFit()

                Text(landmark.name)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .lineLimit(0)

                Toggle(isOn: $modelData.landmarks[landmarkIndex].isFavorite) {
                    Text("Favorite")
                }

                Divider()

                Text(landmark.park)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .bold()
                    .lineLimit(0)

                Text(landmark.state)
                    .font(.caption)

                Divider()

                MapView(coordinates: landmark.locationCoordinates)
                    .scaledToFit()
            }
            .padding(16)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Landmarks")
    }
}

struct LandmarkDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let modelData = ModelData()
        return Group {
            LandmarkDetail(landmark: modelData.landmarks[0])
                .environmentObject(modelData)
                .previewDevice("Apple Watch Series 5 - 44mm")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot for Xcode]

Comment: Put a NavigationView in the Preview area

Answer (score 3):

It still doesn't work in Xcode 14.1 and watchOS 9.1 either in the simulator, or a real device.

```
struct ContentView: View {


@State private var notes: [Note] = [Note]()
@State private var text:String = ""



// MARK: - BODY

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        HStack(alignment:.center,spacing: 6){
            TextField("Add New Note", text: $text)
            
            Button{
                //action
            }label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    .font(.system(size: 52,weight: .bold))
            }
            .fixedSize()
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .navigationTitle("Notes")
  }
}
```

Update:

Using NavigationStack is solved the problem instead of NavigationView

```
 var body: some View{
        NavigationStack{
            VStack{
                Text("Watch Planner")
                    .padding()
                NavigationLink(destination: ProgContentView(viewModel:viewModel)){
                    Text("Program")
                        .padding(.leading,5)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Test")
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to find the way to add the title as well..

Answer (score 0):

I found that it works correctly on simulator after building the project without any code updating. But in preview mode, it's still wrong. I guessed it's a bug from Xcode... Not sure...

[image: Screenshot for simulator]